# How to change the duration of an added game object in multiple empties simultaneously?

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to make an empty that adds a game object be modular.

Suppose that I have an empty with an edit object / add object actuator.

This empty adds a plane that lasts two seconds.

Later, I did make many copies of this empty, so I ended up with a scene with many empties that adds many planes, that lasts two seconds each.

If I want to change the time for which the planes lasts in the scene, to let's say, three seconds, now I need to copy the game logic to the other empties.

I would like to make this in a more modular fashion, by using linked objects instead of selecting many empties to then copy the logic.

Is it possible?

Actually, when in the process of linking the "empty", and change the parameters of the original one, the modifications do not reverberate automatically to the other empties inside the scene, because Blender reads the copies as different objects.

Comment: Both answers are valid, Thank you so much Monster and 
sdfgeoff! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Assign the "template empty" to a new group "Plane.Adder".
- Move the "template empty" to an hidden layer, or scene (does not need to be active), or file (and link the group from there).
- Add any number of instances of group "Plane.Adder" -> Plane.Adder.001, Plane.Adder.002 ...

When you change the duration at the "template empty" the instances inherit this change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making the object vanish a parameter of ... the object doing the vanishing?

As in, the empties all add the object with no time limit, and then in the object, you have a delay sensor to end the object. This way you have a single place to control the lifespan of the object.